# Flex grid: wrong alignment of columns

Tags: angular

### I need the following layout:

Bar       Offset     Data  
dropdown  input      input     button 
dropdown  input      input     button

My grid has 3 rows and 4 columns. 
In the first row, 3 labels. 
In the 2 next rows: 4 controls.

I tried the following code but failed to display the cells in a proper alignment
Can you please help ?

```html
<p-dialog header="PCI" [(visible)]="display">
    <div class="p-grid p-dir-col">
        <div class="p-col">
            <div class="p-grid">
                <div class="p-col-3" >Bar</div>
                <div class="p-col-3" >Offset</div>
                <div class="p-col-3" >Data</div>
                <div class="p-col-3" ></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="p-col">
            <div class="p-grid">
                <p-dropdown class="p-col-3" [options]="dropDownData" [placeholder]="'Select'"></p-dropdown>
                <input class="p-col-3" type="text" pInputText/>
                <input class="p-col-3" type="text" pInputText/>
                <p-button label="Write"></p-button>
            </div> 
        </div>     
             
        <div class="p-col">
            <div class="p-grid">
                <p-dropdown class="p-col-3" [options]="dropDownData" [placeholder]="'Select'"></p-dropdown>
                <input class="p-col-3" type="text" pInputText/>
                <input class="p-col-3" type="text" pInputText/>
                <p-button label="Read"></p-button>
            </div>   
        </div>    
   </div>
</p-dialog>
```

Also - What is the right way to arrange a small space between the columns ?

Thank you in advance,
Zvika

Comment: What css framework is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `p-grid` again and again you can achieve it like

```
<div class="p-grid">
                <div class="p-col-3" >Bar</div>
                <div class="p-col-6" >Offset</div>
                <div class="p-col-3" >Data</div>
                <p-dropdown class="p-col-3" [options]="dropDownData" [placeholder]="'Select'"></p-dropdown>
                <input class="p-col-3" type="text" pInputText/>
                <input class="p-col-3" type="text" pInputText/>
                <p-button label="Write" class="p-col-3" ></p-button>
                <p-dropdown class="p-col-3" [options]="dropDownData" [placeholder]="'Select'"></p-dropdown>
                <input class="p-col-3" type="text" pInputText/>
                <input class="p-col-3" type="text" pInputText/>
                <p-button label="Read" class="p-col-3" ></p-button>
            </div>   
        </div>    
   </div>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dropdown-ojgzx7)

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much. How can I create small space (10px) between elements in each row ?

Comment: @ZviVered add `mrgin-bottom:10px` to each col demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dropdown-nxrtfh

Comment: Your help is highly appreciable. Best regards.